# How to send print log from flutter app?

Tags: debugging, flutter

How to get `print` console log and screen capture so that I can send stack trace to server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a screenshot of the FlutterView using native code.

- On Android: `Bitmap screenshot = flutterView.getBitmap();`
- On iOS, see this [example](https://gist.github.com/nxax/3368089) from Apple.

See the [platform channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) documentation on mixing Dart and native code.

As for the stack trace, here are some tips from the [Flutter Sentry library](https://github.com/flutter/sentry) documentation.

To get a stack trace from within Flutter, override the `onError` handler:

```
FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) async {
  throw details;
};
```

To create a Zone with an error handler that catches all Dart exceptions, wrap your call to `runApp` in [runZoned](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/runZoned.html):

```
runZoned<Future<Null>>(() async {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}, onError: (error, stackTrace) async {
  if (error is FlutterErrorDetails) {
    // use error.exception and error.stack
  } else {
    // use error and stackTrace
  }
});
```

Comment: [Crashy](https://github.com/flutter/crashy/blob/master/lib/main.dart) also have good example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use f_logs package, this has a functionality on export logs to a directory on the phone, it has .db and .txt for the logs, and then you can use flutter_archive package to zip the file, and then use flutter_email_sender to send the zip file that contains the logs your development team. It worked for us, hope this will helps.